# How to CQL filter in WFS request

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs, filter

I am trying to request an WFS url within the circle. With the following url:

> https://localhost:81?request=GetFeature&version=1.0.0&service=WFS&typename=ferrets:ab&outputformat=json&cql_filter=DWITHIN(geom,Point(-232855.14975877, 7787813.215242146),100,kilometers)

But I am getting an error:

> Could not parse CQL filter list. Encountered "," at line 1, column 36. Was expecting one of: "-" ... <INTEGER_LITERAL> ... <FLOATING_LITERAL> ... Parsing : DWITHIN(geom,Point(-232855.14975877,7787813.215242146),100,kilometers).

The same I am trying to implement using the OpenLayers I am facing there error too.

```
function featureRequest(featureType, postalCode) {
        return new ol.format.WFS().writeGetFeature({
          srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
          featureNS: 'http://www.opengeospatial.net/ferrets',
          featurePrefix: 'ferrets',
          featureTypes: [featureType],
          outputFormat: 'application/json',
          filter: ol.format.filter.dwithin('geom', 'Pont(-232855.14975877, 7787813.215242146)', 1000, 'kilometers')
        });
    }
```

Using OpenLayers also I am not able to get jsondata. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4):

Points (`Point(-232855.14975877, 7787813.215242146)` don't have commas as coordinate separators so it should be `Point(-232855.14975877 7787813.215242146)`